# UsageStatsManager doesn't fetch the icons

Tags: javascript, java, ios, react-native

I am using Native Modules from React Native

I'm trying to fetch the apps along with the usage time using the UsageStatsManager, if I just fetch the package name and the usage time it works, but if I try to fetch the package name, the usage time and its respective icon , it returns me only the system apps

I already tried to add the permission

```
\<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /\>
```

but it does not work

How can I make the UsageStatsManager not limit only to system apps ??

Comment: Did you try to add **package usage permission**?